# Can't compile simple c++ QT application sample in NetBeans

Tags: c++, qt, netbeans, configuration, qmake

i'm currently trying to compile the QT sample in Netbeans using QT x64 (installed via MSYS2) and MinGW. But it just doesn't work.

**Output for build**

```
cd 'C:\Users\Thomas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HelloQtWorld_1'
C:\developer\msys2-64\usr\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug QMAKE=/C/developer/msys2-64/mingw64/bin/qmake.exe
"/C/developer/msys2-64/usr/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE=/C/developer/msys2-64/mingw64/bin/qmake.exe SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/c/Users/Thomas/Documents/NetBeansProjects/HelloQtWorld_1'
/C/developer/msys2-64/mingw64/bin/qmake.exe VPATH=. -spec win32-g++ -o qttmp-Debug.mk nbproject/qt-Debug.pro
WARNING: Failure to find: build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/HelloQtWorld_1_resource_res.o
mv -f qttmp-Debug.mk nbproject/qt-Debug.mk
/usr/bin/mv: missing file operand
Try '/usr/bin/mv --help' for more information.
make[1]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: nbproject/qt-Debug.mk] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/Thomas/Documents/NetBeansProjects/HelloQtWorld_1'
make: *** [nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:40: .build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 659ms)
```

**Output for clean and build**

```
cd 'C:\Users\Thomas\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HelloQtWorld_1'
C:\developer\msys2-64\usr\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug clean QMAKE=/C/developer/msys2-64/mingw64/bin/qmake.exe
"/C/developer/msys2-64/usr/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE=/C/developer/msys2-64/mingw64/bin/qmake.exe SUBPROJECTS= .clean-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/c/Users/Thomas/Documents/NetBeansProjects/HelloQtWorld_1'
/C/developer/msys2-64/mingw64/bin/qmake.exe VPATH=. -spec win32-g++ -o qttmp-Debug.mk nbproject/qt-Debug.pro
WARNING: Failure to find: build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/HelloQtWorld_1_resource_res.o
mv -f qttmp-Debug.mk nbproject/qt-Debug.mk
/usr/bin/mv: missing file operand
Try '/usr/bin/mv --help' for more information.
make[1]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: nbproject/qt-Debug.mk] Error 1
make: *** [nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:46: .clean-impl] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/Thomas/Documents/NetBeansProjects/HelloQtWorld_1'

CLEAN FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

**Code**

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // initialize resources, if needed
    // Q_INIT_RESOURCE(resfile);

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // create and show your widgets here

    return app.exec();
}
```

I think QMake and g++ are ok since i can use them in command line however i don't have cmake but i don't think it's important.
If you need other informations tell me because i really wanted to code C++ on netbeans.
Also i'm kind of a noob regarding QT compilation and functionning.

Comment: IMO Creator is a better IDE.

Comment: @dtech what is IMO Creator, i don't even find it on the web. But i use netbeans because it is open source and can support most of the languages i use.

Comment: IMO = in my opinion, Creator is Qt Creator - the native Qt development IDE.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry i'm not english ^^. Well, i'm using it right now because i didn't solve my issue and i prefere netbeans

Comment: The `HelloQtWorld` sample works OK for me... but it's a little bit different - the `newmain.cpp` contains `HelloForm` and building commands don't do anything about resource files. But: it's Linux and Netbeans 8.2. What version of NetBeans do you have?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 and Netbeans 8.2